# I want to use JSON column in efcore 7 with two level only

Tags: json, ef-core-7.0

I am trying to use the new JSON columns in ef core 7. I have two entities only. One is mapped to SQL table, the second one is not. Following are the classes and builder. Using the belowcode, I get the following error on adding the migration:

Entity Type 'B' is mapped to JSON and has a navigation to a regular activity which is not the owner.

I wanted to have B as JSON column in table A.

```
[Table("A")]
public class A {
public long Id { get; set; }
public B b { get; set; }
}

public class B {
public long Id { get; set; }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<A>().OwnsOne(c => c.B, ownedNavigationBuilder => {
ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
});
```

Comment: Also used:
modelBuilder.Entity<A>().OwnsOne(a => a.B, ob => ob.ToJson());